# Python3, get random node from Binary Tree

Tags: python-3.x, random, binary-tree

I built a Binary Search Tree:

```
import random

class Node(object):
 def __init__(self, key):
    self.key = key
    self.leftChild = None
    self.rightChild = None
    self.parent = None

 def hasLeftChild(self):
    if self.leftChild:
        return True
    else:
        return False

 def hasRightChild(self):
    if self.rightChild:
        return True
    else:
        return False

 def isLeftChild(self):
    if self.parent.leftChild == self:
        return True
    else:
        return False

 def isRightChild(self):
    if self.parent.rightChild == self:
        return True
    else:
        return False

 def isRoot(self):
    if not self.parent:
        return True
    else:
        return False


class BinaryTree(object):
 def __init__(self):
    self.root = None
    self.storage = 0

 def addNode(self, newItem):
    if self.storage == 0:
        self.root = Node(newItem)
    else:
        currentNode = self.root
        self.__addNode(currentNode, newItem)
    self.storage += 1

 def __addNode(self, currentNode, newItem):
    if newItem < currentNode.key:
        if currentNode.hasLeftChild():
            self.__addNode(currentNode.leftChild, newItem)

        else:
            currentNode.leftChild = Node(newItem)
            currentNode.leftChild.parent = currentNode
    if newItem > currentNode.key:
        if currentNode.hasRightChild():
            self.__addNode(currentNode.rightChild, newItem)
        else:
            currentNode.rightChild = Node(newItem)
            currentNode.rightChild.parent = self

 def findNode(self, searchKey):
    if self.storage == 0:
        return None
    else:
        if self.root.key == searchKey:
            return self.root
        else:
            currentNode = self.root
            return self.__findNode(currentNode, searchKey)

 def __findNode(self, currentNode, searchKey):
    if searchKey == currentNode.key:
        return currentNode
    if searchKey < currentNode.key:
        if currentNode.hasLeftChild():
            return self.__findNode(currentNode.leftChild, searchKey)
    if searchKey > currentNode.key:
        if currentNode.hasRightChild():
            return self.__findNode(currentNode.rightCHild, searchKey)
    return None

 def getRandomNode(self):
    randomNum = random.randrange(self.storage)
    currentNode = self.root
    self.__getRandomNode(currentNode, randomNum)

 def __getRandomNode(self, currentNode, numCount):
    if numCount == 0:
        print('Find node {0}'.format(currentNode.key))
        return currentNode, numCount
    else:
        if currentNode.hasLeftChild():
            numCount -= 1
            node, numCount = self.__getRandomNode(currentNode.leftChild, numCount)

        if currentNode.hasRightChild():
            numCount -= 1
            node, numCount = self.__getRandomNode(currentNode.rightChild, numCount)
        return None, numCount

print('-----Add Node to BTree-----')
myBinaryTree = BinaryTree() 
myBinaryTree.addNode(15)
myBinaryTree.addNode(10)
myBinaryTree.addNode(20)
myBinaryTree.addNode(9)
myBinaryTree.addNode(13)
myBinaryTree.addNode(12)
print('-----Get Random Node-----')
myBinaryTree.getRandomNode()
```

When I was building the getRandom recursive function, for some of reason, I can only print(make finding random node logically work). But this is really not my main purpose, my main purpose is return the "random node"
Anyone can help me modified the getRandom function and let the "return Node" really work ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would put all the nodes in a list and then get a random between [0; length - 1] and take that node

So another algorithm would require a size property on each node, which is the size of the substree with the node as its root.

Example :
/- 2
1
\- 3 - 4

The size of the node with 1 is 4, the size of the node with 2 is 1, the size of the node with 3 is 2 and the size of the node with 4 is 1

Here is the algorithm :

```
def findNthNode(currentNode, nth):
    if currentNode == None:
        return None
    leftSize = 0
    if currentNode.hasLeftChild():
        leftSize = currentNode.leftChild.size
    if nth == leftSize + 1:
        return currentNode
    elif nth < leftSize + 1:
        return findNthNode(currentNode.leftChild, nth)
    else:
        return findNthNode(currentNode.rightChild, nth - leftSize - 1)
```

Of course you can use a function that returns the size of a tree, but it is way less efficient.

How does it work ?

if there is no current node, we are out of bounds => return None.

if there is no left child, the size of the left subtree is 0.

if the nthNode we want is equals to the leftSize + 1, it means that we have found the node we want, thus we return it.

if the nthNode we want is less than the leftSize + 1, it means that the nthNode is inside the left child. We don't have to change the nthNode since the nodes from the right child are after the nthNode.

if the nthNode we want is greater than the leftSize + 1, it means that the nthNode is inside the right child. But we have to remove the leftSize + 1 because we remove all the nodes from the left which changes the number of nodes before the nthNode.

I hope you understand the algorithm because it's kinda hard to explain

Edit : I totally forgot, this algorithm doesn't give you the nthNode with the preorder traversal, but actually the nth biggest node, hope it still fits your needs

Well I have worked on it, and I just found a solution for the preorder traversal with the same principle :

```
def findNthNode(currentNode, nth):
    if currentNode == None:
        return None
    leftSize = 0
    if currentNode.hasLeftChild():
        leftSize = currentNode.leftChild.size
    if nth == 1:
        return currentNode
    elif nth <= leftSize + 1:
        return findNthNode(currentNode.leftChild, nth - 1)
    else:
        return findNthNode(currentNode.rightChild, nth - leftSize - 1)
```

There are only three modifications :

On the if, you check if nth == 1 since the first element is the root in the preorder traversal.

On the elif:

- You do nth - 1 since you went through the root in the preorder traversal
- You do <= instead of < because you count the root with it

Comment: Hi Alex, your solution is one of the algorithm and I want to use something different :) like read the tree by preorder traversal and stop by RandomNumber(th)

Comment: Here you are, one of the best algorithm to find the nth node in a tree without having to traverse all the tree

Comment: Thank you Alex, I understood your logic; Actually 'nth' is not really the number of nth Node, its really like : give you a random number, return the unique(particular) Node from the input tree. The available randomNumber will be from [1] to [self.storage]. Same randomNumber for different binaryTree might gave you different Node(different position). Anyway, I got the idea, pretty interesting algorithm :)

Comment: Well yeah, considering the second nth (preorder), if you have 'a' with no left child and with 'b' as a right child, nth(2) will give you the right child, but if you have 'a' with 'b' as a left child and no right child, nth(2) will give you the left child tho

Comment: I was thinking about the question again this afternoon, based on your idea (add more properties). I figured a quick and dirty solution for get random node without deal with size and resize (insertion and deletion), see my last comments

Answer (score 0):

Node Class need to be changed:

```
class Node(object):
    def __init__(self, key):
        self.key = key
        self.leftChild = None
        self.rightChild = None
        self.parent = None
        self.size = 0
```

addNode function inside BinaryTree class need to be changed:

```
def addNode(self, newItem):
    if self.storage == 0:
        self.root = Node(newItem)
        self.root.size = 1
    else:
        currentNode = self.root
        self.__addNode(currentNode, newItem)
    self.storage += 1

def __addNode(self, currentNode, newItem):
    if newItem < currentNode.key:
        if currentNode.hasLeftChild():
            self.__addNode(currentNode.leftChild, newItem)

        else:
            currentNode.leftChild = Node(newItem)
            currentNode.leftChild.parent = currentNode
            currentNode.leftChild.size = 1
            self.updateNodeSize(currentNode.leftChild)
    if newItem > currentNode.key:
        if currentNode.hasRightChild():
            self.__addNode(currentNode.rightChild, newItem)
        else:
            currentNode.rightChild = Node(newItem)
            currentNode.rightChild.parent = currentNode
            currentNode.rightChild.size = 1
            self.updateNodeSize(currentNode.rightChild)
```

Also, need to be add new function  after each insertion:

```
def updateNodeSize(self, currentNode):
    if not currentNode.isRoot():
        currentNode.parent.size += 1
        self.updateNodeSize(currentNode.parent)
```

If you have delete function for BinaryTree Class, you also need write new function for update node size after each deletion.
In order to get one random node from existing tree, increase time complexity for both insertion and deletion, this might be another question mark we need think about :)
Anyway, there is no "best code" for same question, but "better code".

Answer (score 0):

in BinaryTree Class, we add these:

```
class BinaryTree(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = None
        self.storage = 0
        self.toatlCount = 0
        self.randomNode = None
```

for add randomNode function, we changed to this:

```
def getRandomNode(self):
    randomNum = random.randrange(self.storage)
    currentNode = self.root
    # initial self.randomNode each time
    self.randomNode = None
    self.__getRandomNode(currentNode, randomNum)
    return self.randomNode

def __getRandomNode(self, currentNode, numCount):
    if self.toatlCount == numCount:
        self.randomNode = currentNode
    else:
        if currentNode.hasLeftChild():
            self.toatlCount += 1
            self.__getRandomNode(currentNode.leftChild, numCount)
        if currentNode.hasRightChild():
            self.toatlCount += 1
            self.__getRandomNode(currentNode.rightChild, numCount)
    return None
```

Based on this solution, you will always get last recursion node based matched condition.